# ASP.NET Cascading DropdownLists not saving back to database

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am new to ASP but I did spend 2 hours searching for this issue. I have a gridview and 2 cascading dropdowns. (Part Group->Part Type)
I am using the code below. The dropdowns work visually when in edit mode. When I click the "Update" link, the Part_Type is always sent back as NULL to the database.  When I use Bind("Part_Type") in the property I get the error "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind ..."

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Part Group" SortExpression="Part_Group">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Part_GroupDD" runat="server" DataSourceID="PartGroupDD" DataTextField="Part_Group" DataValueField="Part_Group" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Product_Group") %>' AutoPostBack="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Product_Group") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Part Type" SortExpression="Part_Type">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="PartType_DD" runat="server" DataSourceID="Part_Type_DD" DataTextField="Part_Type" DataValueField="Part_Type" />
                    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="Part_Type_DD" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationsDBConnect %>"
              SelectCommand="SELECT Part_Group, Part_Type FROM Part.dbo.PartGroup_PartTypeDD" FilterExpression="Part_Group = '{0}'">
            <FilterParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="PartGroup" ControlID="Part_GroupDD"
                 PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            </FilterParameters>                       
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="PartTypelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Part_Type") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is what I found here and tried it 
[2 Dropdownlists in Gridview cause error: Databinding methods such as Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206045/2-dropdownlists-in-gridview-cause-error-databinding-methods-such-as-bind-can)

but I kept getting "Object is not set.." error meaning the label is also null.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            DropDownList DDL1 = e.Row.FindControl("PartType_DD") as DropDownList;

            Label LBL1 = new Label();
            LBL1 = e.Row.FindControl("PartTypelbl") as Label;

            if (LBL1.Text != null)
            {
                DDL1.SelectedValue = LBL1.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to share more html + db saving code + data bind.

Comment: I am using the gridview generated SQL for SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT.  I dont have a binding for the second drop down. I added the attempted bind of the second drop down that didnt work. (The label always seems to be NULL)